# Fetching api response slow and not be stable

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I need to get the value (**totaluser**) as soon as possible , but when the server change the data (**totaluser**) , the reponse is not stable about the time returning , sometimes get the reponse for 30ms and sometimes get for 5000ms , can someone give any solution to get this more stable and get better about the performance ? , i just want to get the value as soon as possible when the server update it?

```
var refreshIntervalId =  setInterval(function () {
        fetch('**the link for api **')
            .then(res => res.json()).then((out) => {

            var variable = out.totalUser[0].count;

        if( variable > 20 ){
           // do something ...
        }
    })  
    }, 10);
```

Comment: 5000 seconds? Usually browsers are aborting a pending AJAX call after 30 seconds. You could lenghten the refresh interval, 10 ms is much too high frequence.

Comment: If you have access to modifying the backend I would suggest looking into websockets to allow the backend to notify the client when the value has been updated.

Comment: @Jim Nilsson ,i am not coding in the backend

Comment: @Teemu ,sorry it is 5 seconds ,5000ms

Comment: @Jim Nilsson ,can i use websockets but i am not coding for the backend ?

Comment: Any solution for this ? Im having some same issue.